# Dynamically Resizing Image Maps?

Tags: javascript, maps, resize

Hope you can help with this problem I've been trying to nut out.

I've found the examples on http://home.comcast.net/~urbanjost/semaphore.html very awesome and work perfectly for what I need.

Only problem is that I'd like the coordinates to dynamically change based on the window size first. The way it works at the moment is that it loads the default coords (works great for resolutions of 1920x1080 but is hugely unaligned on 1024x768) and will then resize on window resize.. I'd like it to detect the size of the browser window for smaller screens first, then display the code accordingly.

Here's my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
//|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||    |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
 GLOBAL_AREAS= new Array();
 GLOBAL_SUFFIX= "g";
 GLOBAL_WIDTH=-1;
 GLOBAL_HEIGHT=-1;
 GLOBAL_NEW_AREAS= new Array();

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 function setglobal(){
    // place original AREA coordinate strings into a global array, called first time setXY is called
    var arrayAreas = document.body.getElementsByTagName("AREA" );
    GLOBAL_WIDTH= document.getElementById("tclteam_s1" ).width; // get original width
    GLOBAL_HEIGHT= document.getElementById("tclteam_s1" ).height; // get original height
    for(var i = 0; i < arrayAreas.length; i++) {
       GLOBAL_AREAS[i]= arrayAreas[i].coords;
    }
    document.body.onresize=setXY('tclteam_s1',XSIZE(),YSIZE());
    // alert("GLOBAL_AREAS" + GLOBAL_AREAS );
 }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

 function setXY(elementid,newwidth,newheight){
    if (GLOBAL_WIDTH == -1 ){
       setglobal();
    }
    document.getElementById(elementid).width=newwidth;
    document.getElementById(elementid).height=newheight;
    scaleArea();
 }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

 function XSIZE(){ // get browser window.innerWidth , dealing with ie
    var myWidth = 1;
    if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
       //Non-IE
       myWidth = window.innerWidth;
    } else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientWidth ) ) {
       //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
       myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    } else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientWidth ) ) {
       //IE 4 compatible
       myWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    }
    return myWidth;
 }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

 function YSIZE(){ // get browser window.innerHeight, dealing with ie
    var myHeight = 1;
    if( typeof( window.innerHeight ) == 'number' ) {
       //Non-IE
       myHeight = window.innerHeight;
    } else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
       //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
       myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    } else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientHeight ) ) {
       //IE 4 compatible
       myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
    }
    return myHeight;
 }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 function scaleArea() { // using values stored at load, recalculate new values for the     current size
    var arrayAreas = document.body.getElementsByTagName("AREA" );
    message = " "
    for(var i = 0; i < arrayAreas.length; i++) {
       ii=i+1;
       rescaleX= document.getElementById("tclteam_s1" ).width/GLOBAL_WIDTH ;
       rescaleY= document.getElementById("tclteam_s1" ).height/GLOBAL_HEIGHT ;
       sarray=GLOBAL_AREAS[i].split("," ); // convert coordinates to a numeric array assuming comma-delimited values
       var rarray =new Array();
       for(var j = 0; j < sarray.length; j += 2) {
          rarray[j]=parseInt(sarray[j])*rescaleX; // rescale the values
          rarray[j]=Math.round(rarray[j]);
          rarray[j+1]=parseInt(sarray[j+1])*rescaleY; // rescale the values
          rarray[j+1]=Math.round(rarray[j+1]);
       }
       message = message + rarray.join("," ) + '\n';
       arrayAreas[i].coords=rarray.join("," ); // put the values back into a string
       GLOBAL_NEW_AREAS[i]= arrayAreas[i].coords;
    }
    // alert(rescaleX + " " + rescaleY + "\n" + GLOBAL_WIDTH + " " + GLOBAL_HEIGHT + "\n" + " GLOBAL_AREAS" + GLOBAL_AREAS + "\nSCALED AREAS" + message);
 }
//||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
</script>
```

The following script here detects the browser window size. So I'm hoping to include this in the above so the image map will dynamically resize from the browser window size first:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var winW = 630, winH = 460;
if (document.body && document.body.offsetWidth) {
 winW = document.body.offsetWidth;
 winH = document.body.offsetHeight;
}
if (document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' &&
    document.documentElement &&
    document.documentElement.offsetWidth ) {
 winW = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
 winH = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
}
if (window.innerWidth && window.innerHeight) {
 winW = window.innerWidth;
 winH = window.innerHeight;
}
</script>
```

Is there a way to code this so it will read the browser window size first (using the code directly above), then load the image map accordingly?

Comment: bet you can do it via media queries, not positive, but without a demo, i can't try it. so post one.